# Will 1099 contract employee receive earning document

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-1099

If you work as a 1099 contract employee where nothing is withheld by the company you’re contracting for, will the company send a 1099 form with earnings similar to normal employees who receive a W2 from their employer?

Comment: Yes, they will furnish you with a copy of the 1099.

Comment: Remember if you have taxable income without withholding you are required to estimate what the tax will be (on form 1040ES) -- for a 1099 contractor including Social Security and Medicare tax -- and make estimated payments 'quarterly' (mid Apr, June, Sep, and Jan which aren't quite quarters) (or if you also have a regular job you can have that employer increase your withholding), and if you don't do this _long before receiving the 1099-MISC_ you will usually owe a penalty (effectively interest) _in addition to_ your actual tax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, unless you are incorporated as a business they have to send you a 1099 if they paid you at least $600.

There are a few exceptions to this rule, but most of them kick in if you are incorporated and they are paying your business instead of you individually. If you were working through a contracting firm that paid you and accepted payment then you would receive either a W2 or 1099 from that firm instead.